# Partial derivatives query

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need some guidance on this partial derivatives question.

I need to work out the partial derivative of the following with respect to $y$:

$$2xy^2e^y + xe^x.$$

Does the product rule apply here, if so, why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the product rule applies. To take the partial derivative, treat all other variables (like $x$) as a constant that does not depend on $y$. You will get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(2xy^2e^y + xe^x\right) = 2x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y^2e^y\right) + 0$$
and now you can use the product rule.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot mate